# Create document library (inside Sharepoint site) through graph APIs?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-api, microsoft-graph-files

When I am trying to create *Document library* using below endpoint its creating folder inside existing document library.

```
POST /drives/{drive-id}/root/children
```

I need to create *Document Library* at site level. e.g. at `https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/<site_name>` through graph APIs

Any Inputs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following endpoint to create a list (Document library):

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/list-create?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Example:

[image]

BR

Comment: Thank you for your reply @baker_kong_msft. I am getting **Access denied** error. I
`{
    "error": {
        "code": "accessDenied",
        "message": "Access denied",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-08-27T06:15:09",
            "request-id": "5b6ede25-ceb9-4f81-b561-***"
        }
    }
}`

 I have below permissions added:
 
 `"Sites.Read.All",
    "Sites.ReadWrite.All",
    "Files.ReadWrite.All",
    "Files.Read.All"
 `

Comment: How about this permission? http://joxi.ru/VrwBdlPH89wLOA